# Flutter: setState Not Updating Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a class that contains a button that I need to update when clicked. This seems like it would be simple, but I cannot get the text to update for some reason. When the button is clicked, I pass a challengesRecord to the class, and I have added a `key` to try to get the widget to update with no luck.

When clicked

```
    fundraiserFlowWidget(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    challengesRecord: challengesRecord,
    ),
```

The class is below. No matter where I put the `setState` call, it still will not update unless I leave the page and come back in. I want the state to change when the `url` is launched so when they come back from the `inAppWebView` the text on the button is changed.

```
    class fundraiserFlowWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    const fundraiserFlowWidget({Key key, this.challengesRecord}) : super(key: key);
        
    final ChallengesRecord challengesRecord;
        
    @override
    State<fundraiserFlowWidget> createState() => _fundraiserFlowWidgetState();
    }
        
    class _fundraiserFlowWidgetState extends State<fundraiserFlowWidget> {
    
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FlatButton(
    //the text on the button should change when the user creates a fundraiser. But it does not unless I go out and come back into the page.
        text: widget.challengesRecord
    .createdFundraiser
    .contains(currentUserReference) ? 'Visit Fundraiser' : 'Create Fundraiser!',

    onPressed: () async {
    //adds user to created fundraiser array
    final challengesUpdateData = {
    'createdFundraiser': FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserReference])
    };
//this is where the user is added is a list who have created a fundraiser
    await widget.challengesRecord.reference.update(challengesUpdateData);
    setState(() {});
    final url = url;
//when coming back form the webView, the state still has not changed
    launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),
    mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
     },
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will solve by putting your logic inside `build()` so when it is called when the state is changed:

```
class _fundraiserFlowWidgetState extends State<fundraiserFlowWidget> {
  bool _hasCreatedFundraiser = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // note here
    _hasCreatedFundraiser = widget.challengesRecord.createdFundraiser.contains(currentUserReference);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      text: _hasCreatedFundraiser ? 'Visit Fundraiser' : 'Create Fundraiser!',
      onPressed: () async {
        final challengesUpdateData = {
          'createdFundraiser': FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserReference])
        };
        await widget.challengesRecord.reference.update(challengesUpdateData);
        setState(() {
          _hasCreatedFundraiser = true; 
        // the update is placed here
        });
        final url = url;
        launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

happy coding....

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I lost several hours trying to get that text to switch over :)